# Force on a ring due to EM induction

Tags: forces, electric-current, electromagnetic-induction

**Question:-** Two circular coils of radii '$a$' , having resistance per unit length $\lambda$, are moving with uniform speed '$v$' along x-axis as shown, in a uniform magnetic field $\vec B=-B_0\hat k$. At t=0, separation between their centres is just greater than $2a$. Find the force on any one circular ring when $\angle AC_1B =60°$[image]

**My Doubt:-** Here, neither magnetic field nor the area vector is changing with time. So, there isn't any current, I think. Then how is the force coming?

Anyone please explain...

Thanks

Comment: But the *area* of the combined loop does change, doesn't it? That matters for the calculation of the flux...

Comment: @Philip Yeah, I got it.. Thanks.

Comment: @AnkanG. How dis you solve it it seems that flux in all 3 areas is changing so deciding the direction of current seems a bit tough I would be glad to know your solution if you answer your question to yourself

Comment: @Anusha Well, take the outward normal to be positive (by convention, you may choose inward too). Let's say the area of the combined loop be $A$, so the area of the remaining loop (of anyone loop) can be found. By similarity, the area of the other loop will be same. Now, in flux we differentiate the area (as area is changing) (taking the combined part into consideration) we get a data. Now for the remaining area of the loop (Area= C-A; C is a constant=π×a^2), when we differentiate it, the value yields to be same. So magnitude wise it came same.

Comment: @Anusha About the direction, we see that area is increasing for a part of the loop and for other part it is decreasing. So by Lenz law, we get a (-)ve sign while computing the direction(as their sense is opposite). So for the entire loop, net EMF is 0 at the given instant (as magnitude is same and adjustment of signs in Lenz Law) so the force comes to be 0. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115417/discussion-between-anusha-and-ankan-g).

Comment: @AnkanG. I've discussed the question with quite a teacher and the answer is not 0 for sure can you confirm

Comment: @Anusha Yeah, I too found. I don't know then. :(

Comment: @Anusha Did he/she give any hint to solve?

Comment: @AnkanG. Yup I have the solution it's a bit complex

Comment: @Anusha Can you please send it? Or, can you tell me the steps?